# Declare C++ array type with dynamic size works fine in Linux, but not Windows

Tags: c++, c++11

With recent gcc versions, I can declare dynamic-sized array data types like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int u;
  scanf("%d", &u);

  using my_type = int[u];
  printf("size of my_type: %d\n", sizeof(my_type));

  return 0;
}
```

This compiles with gcc successfully, and works fine in Linux. Enter 5 for example as input, this will print 20.

But with Windows compiler cl.exe or VS2015 itself, I receive compile error:

```
error C2540: non-constant expression as array bound
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: VLA's are a compiler extension, that's not standard c++. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead to make that work in a portable manner.

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the C++ standard, but some compilers may have them as an *extension* of the language. Generally, don't use them. If you want a dynamically-sized "array" use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays were never a standard C++ feature. Some compilers support it as an extension, but not all. *Don't* rely on it. You want `std::vector`. And add `-Wvla -Werror` to your compiler flags.

Comment: You can solve it by using the `std::vector` class template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid portable C++. This is a C99 extension (Variable Length Array) to GCC that is not available with any Visual Studio version.